# store list names inside a list in Python

Tags: python

How can I store list names inside a list in Python?

I have six lists that I need to combine into one big list. If any list from six lists is empty then I want to add empty brackets "()" to this final big list to indicate an empty list.

Here is what I tried but it didn't work as I stored list names as strings inside a masterList,

```
masterList=["primaryP","primaryG","primaryAin","primaryAout","primaryDin","primaryDout"]


primaryP=['VDD']
primaryG=['VSS']
primaryAin=[]
primaryAout=[]
primaryDin=['A', 'X', 'M', 'SEL']
primaryDout=['Y']

for item in masterList:
    if item==[] :
        item=["()"]
    else:
        item=' '.join(item)
        item=[item]

CSRPGPrimary=primaryP+primaryG+primaryAin+primaryAout+primaryDin+primaryDout

print("CSRPGPrimary=", CSRPGPrimary)
```

This produces below output:

```
('CSRPGPrimary=', '//PG PRIMARY ("VDD") ("VSS") ("A") ("X") ("M") ("SEL") ("Y")')
```

However, output I want is

```
('CSRPGPrimary=', '//PG PRIMARY ("VDD") ("VSS") () () ("A X M SEL") ("Y")'
```

any inputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, this is what you want:

```
masterList=[primaryP, primaryG, primaryAin, primaryAout, primaryDin, primaryDout]
CSRPGPrimary = ['("'+' '.join(item)+'")' if item else '()' for item in masterList]
```

Note that in your `for` loop, modifying `item` doesn't modify the lists contents, it just reassigns the reference. (`item` points to the element of the list, then you just make it point to something else, it does nothing to the list itself)

Comment: this is a good one liner but missing double quotes. I need double quotes around every non-empty list, here is the output from your code: ('CSRPGPrimary=', ['(VDD)', '(VSS)', '()', '()', '(A X M SEL)', '(Y)'])
 and here is the desired output: ('CSRPGPrimary=', ['("VDD")', '("VSS")', '()', '()', '("A X M SEL")', '("Y")'])

Comment: updated code give dobule quotes for empty brackets as well. here is the output: ('CSRPGPrimary=', ['"(VDD)"', '"(VSS)"', '"()"', '"()"', '"(A X M SEL)"', '"(Y)"'])

Comment: Thank you very much, small and neat solution!!

Answer (score 2):

```
CSRPGPrimary = []

primaryP=['VDD']
primaryG=['VSS']
primaryAin=[]
primaryAout=[]
primaryDin=['A', 'X', 'M', 'SEL']
primaryDout=['Y']

masterList=[primaryP,primaryG,primaryAin,primaryAout,primaryDin,primaryDout]

for item in masterList:
    if item:
        CSRPGPrimary.append( "(" + ' '.join(item) + ")" )
    else:
        CSRPGPrimary.append("()")



print("CSRPGPrimary=", CSRPGPrimary)

CSRPGPrimary= ['(VDD)', '(VSS)', '()', '()', '(A X M SEL)', '(Y)']
```

Comment: Now it's basically an expanded version of my 1-liner. And the `if else` block is unnecessary...

Answer (score 1):

Why store list names instead of the lists themselves?

```
masterList = [primaryP, primaryG, primaryAin, primaryAout, primaryDin, primaryDout]
```

Additionally, it would probably be easier to print the value instead of modifying the item in your loop. That should get you the output you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Masterlist values are not being changed in your code.

```
primaryP = ['VDD']
primaryG = ['VSS']
primaryAin = []
primaryAout = []
primaryDin = ['A', 'X', 'M', 'SEL']
primaryDout = ['Y']

masterList = [primaryP, primaryG, primaryAin, primaryAout, primaryDin, primaryDout]

for i in range(0, len(masterList)):
    if len(masterList[i]) == 0:
        masterList[i] = ["()"]
    else:
        masterList[i] = ' '.join(masterList[i])
        masterList[i] = ["(" + masterList[i] +")"]

CSRPGPrimary = masterList[0] + masterList[1] + masterList[2] + masterList[3] + masterList[4] + masterList[5]
#primaryP + primaryG + primaryAin + primaryAout + primaryDin + primaryDout

print("CSRPGPrimary=", CSRPGPrimary)
```

> Answer

```
CSRPGPrimary= ['(VDD)', '(VSS)', '()', '()', '(A X M SEL)', '(Y)']
```

Comment: Remove all the unnecessary stuff and you basically reduce that to a 1-liner like in my solution...